# remote dial using SIP client

Tags: voip, sip, sdp

I want to remote dial from my pc using a simple non SIP client program which I wrote and wchich sends commands to a proprietary SIP client that accepts remote commands via a TCP connection. The proprietary SIP client will then dial the remote party using my PC's IP and port number in SDP for RTP. Is this possible in principle? Are there any opensource clients available that use this concept? Is there any documentation (IETF RFCs, blogs etc) that is available.

Appreciate any help in this matter.

Comment: What's the protocol of your prop. SIP client? What client is it? please give more details!

Comment: The prop SIP client uses SIP to communicate with a softswitch (asterisk, freeswitch etc) on one side. It communicates with my TCP client using a simple proprietary request-response commands on the other end.

Comment: OK so what's the problem, if you know the protocol?

Comment: I want to do it without using SIP in my TCP client. Is it possible?

Comment: I don't know this domain. I was just here to try to understand your question, because it helps make it clearer. You should really reformulate (title too)

Answer (score 0):

Check out [pjsip](http://www.pjsip.org), it's an open-source cross-platform SIP client for all major platforms and with API in C and an API wrapper for python, whichever you prefer. There are also examples on their site. Link your TCP parsing code to pjsip and call its functions to initiate a call, you can find how to do it on their site

Comment: The PJSIP and TCP client are on different machines. How can I get the RTP feed to my remote TCP client. I thought of specifying remote port and remote IP address for that. But will this work? Any ideas? Thanks for your response.

Comment: Theoretically it might be possible to redirect the RTP stream to a third IP by carefully tuning the SDP parameters of the INVITE message, but I've never done this or never heard anybody who would do it, so no success is guaranteed. Start here: http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2327.txt

Comment: Does the Skype4b Android SDK support allowing the SDP portion of the message to be modified, such that the media RTP streams will be routed to a different IP address and port than what the application is running on? 

Can the remote connection's SDP information be extracted, so the information can be sent to a Linux box?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, here is what you want to do:

```
    TCP              SIP/SDP/RTP
PC <===> SIP client <===========> softswitch
```

Actually, TCP between PC and SIP client will probably be accurate for signalling but not for media as RTP media stream is often sent over UDP.

In my opinion, the first step is to make sure that your softswitch will accept sending RTP packets to an IP address which is not the same as SIP client (I think most of them refuse for security reasons). If it accepts and if you have no NAT between your SIP client and your PC, you should be able to send RTP stream directly to your PC. In this case, you have to retrieve RTP packets, eventually rearrange them, decompress their payload and feed them to your speakers.

If your softswitch does not want to send RTP packets to an IP address different from SIP IP address, then you have to forward your RTP packets from your SIP client to your PC. But if you can't modify your SIP client to do this (and it's probably the case as it's a proprietary software), you're probably stuck.

To test whether your softswitch accepts sending RTP packets to an unintended IP address, you can use [sipp](http://sipp.sourceforge.net/) and specify a remote media ip address different from SIP signalling IP address.

Comment: Does the Skype4b Android SDK support allowing the SDP portion of the message to be modified, such that the media RTP streams will be routed to a different IP address and port than what the application is running on? 

Can the remote connection's SDP information be extracted, so the information can be sent to a Linux box?